# Should reputation requirement for moderator be increased?

Tags: discussion, reputation, moderation, moderators

Currently the reputation requirement for using moderator tools set at 2,000 points. Seeing as many members are reaching that limit, should it be increased?

Answer (score 11):

When the site graduates the reputation requirement for access to the tools menu will increase to 10K - in line with Stack Overflow et al.

Reduced reputation requirements is a feature of beta. During the private beta the requirements were different again.

Lower requirements are needed to allow the site to evolve into it's final form and during the initial phases more people who can cast close votes and edit other people's post are needed. As the site matures and what's on topic and off topic settles to it's final version the same tasks can be accomplished with fewer voters plus the diamond moderators.

Comment: Does that mean existing moderators lose their responsibilities/privileges?

Comment: @Mark if you mean those users with 2,000 reputation then "yes". The diamond moderators keep theirs (obviously). Lower rep users will lose the privileges they currently have too.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 3):

If the members have proven themselves worthy of the reputation, I see no reason to ensure it remains only a privileged few that can use moderator tools.